# Firebase email template for Scope to a tenant

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-identity

I modified the email template for "reset password". If the user is out of tenant scope on Identity Planform - the template works fine. But when the user is in tenant scope - the template not working.

**User out of scope**:

IDP: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNO8S.png

Email: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7B4ra.png

**User in scope of tenant**:

IDP: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q42EP.png

Email: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dB6o.png

```
export const resetPassword = (email) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const userSnapshot = await firebase.db.collection(USER_DATA_COLLECTION).where('email', '==', email).get();
    firebase.auth.tenantId = userSnapshot.docs[0].data().tenantId;
    return await firebase.doResetPassword(email);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};
```

Comment: please see my suggestion below and lmk if it works!

Answer (score 4):

Currently, Google Cloud Identity Platform (GCIP) and Firebase Auth do not support tenant specific email templates.

You can update tenant metadata to allow the tenant to inherit custom domains, email templates, and custom SMTP settings. If [`emailSendingConfig`](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.tenants#inheritance) is set to `true` emails sent from tenant will follow the project level email sending configurations. If `false` (by default), emails will go with the default settings with no customizations (e.g. custom domain attached to email template will not be applied). You can set this field by executing the below cURL command:

```
curl -d "{'inheritance':{'emailSendingConfig': true}}"\
-H 'Authorization: Bearer AUTH_TOKEN' \
-X PATCH -H 'Content-Type:application/json' \
https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v2/projects/PROJECT_ID/tenants/TENANT_ID?updateMask=inheritance.emailSendingConfig
```

### *Notes for the parameters passed to the above cURL command*

The `AUTH_TOKEN` will need the scopes listed in the [Identity Toolkit REST API documentation](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.tenants/patch). One of the easier ways for you to retrieve the auth token for the REST
command is to have a project owner use
[OAuthPlayground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) and authorize
the
*Identity Toolkit API v3 scopes*

[image: Identity Toolkit API v3 scopes]

`TENANT_ID` is the actual tenant id as opposed to the display name, this can be obtained via the `GCIP > Tenant` Cloud Console page.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the admin API to inherit [emailSendingConfig](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.tenants#inheritance). Emails sent from tenant will now follow the project-level email sending configuration.

Comment: The link you provided only works for Google employees, not all of us are.